# How to build an ExtJS application using open tooling?

Tags: extjs

To build an ExtJS application using sencha cmd I used the command below

```
sencha app build
```

But how I can build using open tooling? The docs is not clean about build application with open tooling.

Comment: Some good discussion around this here.  https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?303145-How-can-I-create-new-Extjs-6-application-without-sencha-cmd&p=1108063&viewfull=1.  Also, directions on how some people have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm run build` should do the job

Check your `package.json`, you normally have a `script` section

Answer (score 0):

You could build the app using the commands

npm run build:desktop

npm run build:phone

The above commands used based on the package.json file script section.Below is the snippet of code of script section of package.json file.

"scripts": {
"start": "npm run dev:desktop",
"clean": "rimraf build",
"dev:desktop": "webpack-dev-server --env.profile=desktop --env.browser=yes --env.verbose=no",
"dev:phone": "webpack-dev-server --env.profile=phone --env.browser=yes --env.verbose=no",
"build:desktop": "npm run clean && cross-env webpack --env.profile=desktop --env.environment=production --env.treeshake=yes",
"build:phone": "npm run clean && cross-env webpack --env.profile=phone --env.environment=production --env.treeshake=yes"
}

Answer (score 0):

We were suffering a lot and spent significant effort to find the tooling what suits our needs the best. Finally we ended up using webpack because there is a large ecosystem around that so it opened up endless possibilities.
Although sencha did some webpack plugins but they are mostly just watching changes. Therefore we have created a webpack loader what is resolving ext's dependencies. This [webpack loader](https://github.com/zmagyar/extjs-loader) will allow to use webpack to build your ext project. There is a [small sample](https://github.com/zmagyar/extjs-loader-sample) to help to configure it.